# Calling functions within Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

I'm struggling to call functions inside my polymer element. I know that you need to use `this.functionName();`, and it works.

but when I was it in a setTimeout like this: `runSoon = setTimeout(this.runNow(), 12000);` it runs without waiting.
If I write it like this: `runSoon = setTimeout(function(){this.runNow()}, 12000);` it gives me an error message: `Uncaught TypeError: this.runNow is not a function`.

Also, when I use this.functionName in a Firebase it works, but in "forEach", like in this example, it gives my that error `Uncaught TypeError: this.myFunction is not a function`:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    this.myFunction();
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be without `()`

```
runSoon = setTimeout(this.runNow, 12000);
```

this way you pass a referenc to the function `this.runNow`

```
runSoon = setTimeout(this.runNow(), 12000);
```

passes the result of `this.runNow()` to `setTimeout(...)`

Comment: yep. that works. but now then I try to call another function from runNow, this.nextStep(); , it gives me that error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: this.nextStep is not a function'. also, the second way I did it is supposed to work.

Comment: try `this.runNow.bind(this)` instead of just `this.runNow`

Comment: Yup, that's critical (and cumbersome) in JS.